# Dynatable json data with spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dynatable

I'm attempting to write data using dyntable to an html table. One of the headers is called `Week of year`. In the JSON file, the name is also `Week of year` (with the spaces). When passing the json to dynatable:

```
$('#week_table').dynatable({
    dataset: {
        records: [{"Week of year":"June 9, 2014 to June 15, 2014","a":0.0,"b":0.0,"c":0.0,"d":0.0,"e":1.0,"f":0.0},{"Week of year":"June 16, 2014 to June 22, 2014","a":0.0,"b":0.0,"c":5.0,"d":0.0,"e":16.0,"f":0.0}]
}});
```

and drawing to an html table:

```
  <table id="week_table">
    <thead>
      <th>weekOfYear</th>
      <th>Week of year</th>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
      <th>f</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The table draws fine for `a` to `f`, but appears as undefined for both `weekOfYear` and `Week of year`. How do you pass json to dynatable that contains spaces?

Comment: Your `dataset` object appears to be missing an ending brace.

Comment: That was a typo while making the example. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's very odd. It didn't seem to work for me at first either, but here's a link to a working example with your data. Hopefully this helps

http://jsfiddle.net/jmtw1tpr/

I changed

```
<th>weekOfYear</th>
```

to

```
<th>week</th>
```

Comment: It looks like it's related to the naming convention of the JSON properties. Try using all lower case as shown in the documentation: http://www.dynatable.com/?sorts%5Bus-%24%5D=-1#converting-attribute-names

Comment: I wish I could control the json format... Just slightly below I found the hidden line in the documentation I was looking for. Changing the header to <th data-dynatable-column="Week of year">Week of year</th> solved the problem.